# knockout-validation change input background color on invalid model

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

For [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/8PVwn/4/), how can i make the background color of the box change when the model is invalid?

```
ko.validation.configure({
    insertMessages: false,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorElementClass: 'error'
});

NameModel = function(model) {
    var self = this;

    //Observables
    self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });

    ko.validation.group(self);
    return self;
};
```

I am trying to achieve something similar to the store checkout below.

[image: checkout]

Comment: De you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XxUrg/?

Comment: Add an error class like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/8PVwn/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout-Validation plugin adds an `error` class to the elemnts which are not valid. All you need to do is set the background color for that class:

```
.error {
    background: yellow;
}
```

If you need to change the element error class you cand do that too. More info in the configuration section of the documentation (https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration).